# Why Constructor is not Calling with Function call Operators

Tags: c++, constructor

Sorry I was unable to find any keyword to search for this problem. My code is below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Name {
    public:
        Name() {
            cout << "Asif";
        }
};

int main() {
    Name obj(); // why Constructor not calling here?

    return 0;
}
```

If it's not calling the constructor then what process is running in this code?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse -- `Name obj{};` disambiguates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Name obj(); // why Constructor not calling here?
```

This is a function declaration, returning a Name object

Just do

```
Name obj;
```

Comment: My Stupid Mind... -_- Got it thanks..!!